# Python Oracle Date Parameters

Tags: python-2.7, oracle11g, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass a date into Oracle 2 different ways when running Python code.

1. Be able to pull the first day of last month and the last day of last month automatically from `datetime.date`.  I found this code online, but not sure that it will produce the first day of last month and the the last day of last month.

   ```
   import datetime  
   today = datetime.date.today()    
   first = datetime.date(day=1, month=today.month, year=today.year)      
   lastMonth = first - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
   ```
2. In case of situations that I will need to manually enter the date for prior dates, etc.  I want to be able to manually enter a beginning and end date.  First off is there a way to have Python prompt me to enter start date and end date?  Secondly, I can't seem to get my code to work correctly when I try to put the dates in my code.

   ```
   Import dateutil.parse   
   start = dateutil.parser.parse('06/01/2015')   
   end = dateutil.parser.parse('06/30/2015')
   startdate = start.strftime('%d-%b-%y')    
   enddate = end.strftime('%d-%b-%y')    
   cursor = con.cursor()   
   cursor.execute(SELECT * From Executives WHERE DateAdded >= %s And DateAdded <= %s), (startdate, enddate)
   ```

I have even tried `DateAdded >= :s` and `DateAdded <= :e`. but I am still getting an error.

Comment: *"not sure that it will produce the first day of last month and the the last day of last month"* - why not? Have you tested it?

Comment: I haven't figured out part 2 of the code in order to pass it to Oracle and pull the date ranges I need, so no I haven't tested it yet until I can figure out what I am doing wrong with the second code.

Comment: That seems foolish, frankly - why not test each part in isolation before trying to put it together? Your second part isn't currently valid Python (`'Import' != 'import'` and you're treating the query as if it was code), you should at least get it to *run* first.

Comment: I have tested my code in regards to pulling the data down from Oracle and putting into an Excel file and that works just fine.  I just don't want the contents of the entire table, I want to be able to only pull data from this tables between two dates and I can't figure out to type the where clause in my code to get the dates to pull correctly based upon a manually inputted date or automated date...